# Is there other web browser implementations other then webkit,mozila?

Tags: browser, embedding

im looking to embed web browser in my application , (static linking none lgpl/gpl). 
are there any other web browsers that allow static linking without gpl/lgpl license restrictions?
i need it to be cross platform.

Answer (score 1):

Gecko, the rendering engine used by Mozilla Firefox, is embeddable under the MPL, not the GPL/LGPL. The MPL [can be combined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Public_License) with proprietary code.

See this FAQ entry: [What are the license terms for embedding Gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Embedding_FAQ/Introduction_to_Gecko_and_Embedding#What_are_the_license_terms_for_embedding_Gecko.3F)

Also, from a technical standpoint, [this article](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/embedding/) should contain everything you need to know about embedding Gecko.

Comment: i think i read this once , its involve to use the xulrunner full components , its to big for me ..

Comment: I think you'll find most of the major renderers are very big.